# Gson: How to use a custom serializer only with some annotations?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I have some classes containing integer IDs, something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  int myId;
  // Other fields
}
```

I need a way to use a custom serializer only in certain cases (so that I cannot use @JsonAdapter) and of course I cannot generically use this serializer for all the integer values, because sometimes I want a sort of transformation of my ID (i.e. this is a web server response and I want to mask my ids so that they cannot be reused).

The full data model is quite complex and deep, and I annotated all the ID fields (even when they are collections) with a custom annotation @MyId. The point is that I don't find a valid way to say to a Gson instance "please, use this serializer for fields annotated with @MyId.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON Custom serialization with annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813354/gson-custom-serialization-with-annotations)

Comment: It seems to me that in the question you posted you only can force a specific field to have a custom adapter everytime. My adapter instead is not mandatory on that field and it must have some parameters.

Comment: So you want to use the custom adapter on specific fields... sometimes? based on what is _sometimes_? Maybe control it in the JsonAdapter then?

Comment: For example, I want to have a specific adapter for each single HTTP session (so a Gson instance with the "id transformer adaptor" with a sort of custom "encryption key". And I also need sessions without any encryption at all (not a big issue if the previous case is covered).

Comment: In JsonSerializer you get passed the type, which contains the annotations. Then just create a gson instance every time and give the serializer the required context information